# Angular2 Material Date picker issue using DD-MM-YYYY format, while opening Date picker popup

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular2-forms, angular-material2

I have applied Custom date adapter. But while opening the picker take current month as display view.

Here is my code :

```
export class MyDateAdapter extends NativeDateAdapter {

    format(date: Date, displayFormat: Object): string {
        if (displayFormat === 'input') {
            const day = date.getDate();
            const month = date.getMonth() + 1;
            const year = date.getFullYear();
            return `${day}-${month}-${year}`;
         } else {
             return date.toDateString();
         }
    }
}

const MY_DATE_FORMATS = {
parse: {
    dateInput: 'dd-mm-YYYY',// { month: 'short', year: 'numeric', day: 'numeric' },
},
display: {
    dateInput: 'input',
    monthYearLabel: { year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric' },
    dateA11yLabel: { year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' },
    monthYearA11yLabel: { year: 'numeric', month: 'long' },
},
```

};

```
{ provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MyDateAdapter },
{ provide: MD_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_DATE_FORMATS },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enforce date-picker to show your chosen date by using attribute `[startAt]` and binding value of `[(ngModel)]`.

There is issue with material2 component when you use custom date format.